# Incrementing an ID name and getting value into a JS variable

Tags: javascript, php

Let's say I have a number of select fields. The quantity of those select fields is not fixed. They will be genereated by the user. BUT they will have an incremented ID like this:

```
<select id="select1"></select>
<select id="select2"></select>
<select id="select3"></select>
```

What I need is for a JavaSript to pull the values from those selects based on their ID, assuming I have the CURRENT count of the selects in another variable.

So I'm looking for somehting to make this work like:

```
for (var i =1; i<currentcount; i++){
var resultvar = select(//now I have to add the var i in here but don't know how).value;
alert(resultvar);
}
```

Comment: document.getElementById('select' + i).value

Comment: you don't even need to keep the count in another variable necessarily. If you give all the selects the same class, you can easily use script to pull out all the elements with that class at any given moment, and loop through them to get the values.

Comment: you can get all select by this `$('select.yourclassname').each(function() {`.

Comment: @urfusion is there jQuery in this code anywhere? No.

Comment: @Danmoreng : Yes, I know, Thanks for pointing this out. I am trying to providing an alternate way. Is there any issue with that?

Comment: @urfusion you should at least say that this command is using a library and not vanilla js...

Comment: @Danmoreng : has he mention something like `vanilla js` ? Ohh, Sorry

Comment: @urfusion If the question has no jQuery tag and the code shows no sign of the usuage of the library, you can assume he is not using it. Therfor if you suggest an answer which is using a library, you should at least say that it's from a library.

Comment: @Quentin I'm really not sure that duplicate is directly related to this. This question is asking how to loop through a dynamically generated list of elements. The duplicate you've marked is to to with accessing object properties using a string to represent the property. Here the OP could either generate the ID selector strings dynamically (I guess this is what you had in mind, but selectors are not object properties), or a better solution would be to use a class. Not really the same thing as accessing object properties.